# Necessary and Sufficient Conditions - Nehari

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

I want to find necessary and sufficient conditions in order that the following problem has a solution:

Given complex numbers $a_0,\ldots,a_n$  consider the problem to find all complex function $f$,
$$
f(\lambda)=\sum_{\nu=0}^{\infty}{\lambda^\nu f_\nu},
$$

satisfying the following three conditions:

- $f_j=a_j$ for $j=0,\ldots,n$;
- $\sum_{\nu=0}^{\infty}|f_\nu|<\infty$;
- $\sup_{\lambda\in \mathbb{D}}|f(\lambda)|<1,$ where $\mathbb{D}$ is the open unit disk in the complex plane.

First, I had no idea how to start, however after some research I found out that this problem looks similar to a Nehari extension problem. see: https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Nehari_extension_problem

Apparently, a lot is known about the Nehari extension problem. So, I have tried to reduce my problem to a Nehari EP to use the existence theorems, but have had no success. How can I transform this system into a Nehari extension problem?

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean $\sup_\lambda |f(\lambda)|$?  Supremum over what set?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Sorry. See edit.